# Indexing Pairs <key, value> and return results ordered by value on Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a collection of users. Each user has some fields. One of those fields is a map, like: "key, value" in witch the value represents the order.

For example:

`user1` has:

```
id    = user1
tags  = <apples, 100>, <bananas, 80>, <oranges, 60>
name  = "Ann Miller"
likes = "apples and skydiving, and sometimes solving puzzles"
quote = "Never spent a day without a smile!"
```

`user2` has:

```
id    = user2
tags  = <bananas, 100>, <pears, 80>, <apples, 60>
name  = "Mike Anderson"
likes = "sleep and eating pizza"
quote = "Math, it's a puzzle to me. I love figuring out puzzles."
```

I want a general search that returns the user, something in the likes of:

```
search  |  result order
--------+--------------------
smile   | user1
puzzle  | user2, user1
bananas | user2, user1
apples  | user1, user2
```

Currently I have a general filed to witch I copy the values of each of the fields, and then I make the search on that field. Now I only put the key of the pairs in it, so the ordering is not the one I want.

I use SolrJ to index the document (extracted from a database) and to search.

I have thought of repeating the words like 100 times for apples, 80 for bananas, etc, but that strikes me as extremely and painfully slow (besides not being a good way to make it).

Do any of you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on Andrea's suggestion, a solution could be in these lines:

- Index the values as dynamic fields (e.g. `*_value` as in `banana_value`).
- Using the [eDisMax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) [boost or bf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#boost_.28Boost_Function.2C_multiplicative.29) your search results using something like `bf=field($value_field)` where `value_field` is an additional param that you specify using SolrJ. Through this param you will provide the **query term + the dynamic field suffix** (e.g. banana_value) and, thanks of the function query [field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#field) you will obtain the value for that particular pair and boost the result accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm I'm not sure but I think it's not possible...a sort field must be monovalued (multivalued doesn't make sense) and I suppose you have a multivalued field.

Now let's suppose you index each value of the map as a dynamic field (field name is the key and field value is the corresponding weight)...here you solved the monovalued issue but you got another interesting problem...the name of the sort field cannot be determined at query time because it depends on search matches...